# Setting an object attribute from a hidden field Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to update an `Idea` attribute `challenge_id` through a hidden form field. Here is the field:

`<%= f.hidden_field :challenge_id, :value => @challenge.id %>`

It successfully passes the challenge id as a param when an idea is created to the Idea Controller#create method:

`Started POST "/ideas.js" for ::1 at 2015-06-18 15:39:49 -0400
Processing by IdeasController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "idea"=>{"title"=>"adsf", "description"=>"asf", "domain_tokens"=>"20", "challenge_id"=>"5"}, "commit"=>"Create Idea"}`

This `challenge_id => 5` should then be saved to the idea in the line `@idea = Idea.new(idea_params)` below:

**ideas_controller.rb**

```
def create
    @idea = Idea.new(idea_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @idea.save
        idea_count = @idea.user.ideas_created_count
        @idea.user.update(:ideas_created_count => idea_count + 1)
        @idea.domains.each do |domain|
          current_user.add_points(1, category: domain.title)
        end
        @ideas = current_user.current_team.ideas.sort_by{|i| i.heat_index}.reverse
        @ideas = @ideas.paginate(:page => params[:ideas_page], :per_page => 10)
        format.html { redirect_to :back, notice: 'Idea was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @idea }
        format.js
      else
        format.html { redirect_to :back, notice: "You must attach domains to your Idea." }
        format.json { render json: @idea.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.js { render :create_failed }
      end
    end
  end
  .
  .
  def idea_params
   params.require(:idea).permit(:title, :description, :challenge_id)
  end
```

However, this challenge id isn't being saved to the `idea` with the other permitted `idea_params`, `:title` and `:description`.  How can I get `challenge_id` to be saved to the Idea when it's created?

Comment: What `puts params` in the very first row of this method would print?

Comment: and also what `idea_params` is returning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using hidden field, why not pass in the challenge_id in your form?  Otherwise, you leave open the possibility that users can enter whatever they want in that hidden field.

Form:

```
form_for [@challenge, Idea.new] do |f|
```

And then:

```
def create
    @challenge = Challenge.find(params[:challenge_id])
    @idea = Idea.new(idea_params)
    @idea.challenge_id = @challenge.id
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have challenge_id column in ideas table.

Try something like:

```
def create
    @idea = Idea.new(idea_params)
    @idea.challenge_id = params[:idea][:challenge_id]
     #...
 end
```

If you params or column you want to save it to is different, make sure to make the change, but you get the idea.